# Share data between two iPhone applications iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile

Is it possible to fetch data of another application in my iPhone to my app , when I triggered event in that.

For example , I have once secret value in 'B' app. That value I want to use in 'A' app for other purpose . So When I click retrieve button in 'A' app , I wanted to retrieve data from 'B' app ?

Note : FYI , both apps are belongs to same dev account. SO , we can achieve with Key chain shared groups but , I am expecting alternative way.

Comment: Why don't you just want to use the cloud? All secret values can be uploaded to the cloud and can be fetched from the cloud? 

I'm not sure if its possible to communicate between apps like you are trying to do

Comment: Thank you . Nice idea . But my app should work even in offline.

Comment: We can't achieve with custom URL schema or App extensions approach right ?

Comment: You can use `App Group`, it will give you a shared container between your apps

Comment: try custom url schema

Comment: With Custom URL we can able to pass the data from 'A' app to 'B' app. But we can't fetch 'B' apps data from 'A' app as I mentioned above.                Please correct me If I made wrong statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share secret values between two apps you should use Keychain Sharing. You have to turn it on in each app's capabilities and use the same group name for both.

Comment: Can I use App group instead of Keychain sharing ?

Comment: Of course you can use that, too but because you wrote "secret value" I initially thought of keychain.

Comment: Why ? App group is not secure way of sharing data . What about custom URL schema . With custom URL schema can we fetch data of 'B' application from 'A' application ?